# Matrix Equation $AB=TA$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

For square real matrices $A$ and $B$, if $A$ is nonsingular, we have:
$$AB=TA$$
with $T=ABA^{-1}$. My question is about the case when $A$ is singular. What are the conditions to guarantee the existence of the matrix $T$ such that $AB=TA$. How to find the solution $T$ in terms of $A$ and $B$.

Thanks,

Comment: I believe $\ker(A) \subseteq \ker(AB)$ should be necessary and sufficient.